# run a background terminal process in python loop one by one

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, os.system

I want to execute this command in terminal shell using python:

command= `'program.x input.in output.out &'`

I need to keep updating the input files with different parameters so I am using a python for loop to do so.

My code looks something like this:

```
for i in range ():
    *code to update input file here*

    os.system(command)
```

What I want to do is in every loop, I want to let the os.system process finish first before moving to the next loop. But When I try my code, the python runs the loop all at once, and I have like 10 different `command` processes running in the background of my system. Is there any way I can run these processes in background while running the loop one by one until a process is finished?

When I remove that ' &' sign from the command, the code works well so it is only an issue with background processes.

Comment: You answered it yourself - when you remove the ampersand ("&") the code works well. The ampersand means to start the command as a background process without waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Since i am working on a remote system using ssh, whenever I disconnect, the program stops! Hence I need to use that ampersand to get my job done. Is it possible to still get it working with the ampersand

Comment: In that case, you might want to use screen, tmux or nohup.